# HttpClient pass ClaimsIdentity to another WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, httpclient, adfs2.0

Im using a transparent proxy, is it possible to pass the claims identity to another WebAPI?

I have two WebAPI's, the presentation and the applicational, both use ADFS to authenticate.

My code so far to process the presentation requests to the Applicational WebAPI

```
//Obtain ClaimsIdentity (Contains claims)
ClaimsPrincipal icp = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal;
ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)icp.Identity;

var baseAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationalWebApiUrl"] + "/" + url;

var http = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(baseAddress));

http.Accept = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
http.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
http.Method = "GET";

//Doesn't pass the ClaimsIdentity
http.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

try
{
    //Get the requested data
    var response = http.GetResponse();

    var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
    var contentResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();

    return Request.CreateResponse(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object>(contentResponse));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: "Passing" credentials to another webapi is the same a "delagating" the identity impersonation - So you probably need to set the ´request.ImpersonationLevel´ to ´Delegation´

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad unfortunately, no.

Comment: If you are using OAuth have a look at this http://bitoftech.net/2014/09/24/decouple-owin-authorization-server-resource-server-oauth-2-0-web-api/

Comment: I am currently struggling with this problem. @BrunoMartinsPro did you find a solution?

Comment: @StianStandahl unfortunately no..

Comment: i realized it myself. Ended up with using access token method.

Answer (score 0):

In your first `API` getting `Auth` from the user you need to just pass that information to further requests. You can propagate all headers, or just `Authorization` header with `bearer token` (which has inside the claims details). You can add custom data to headers and read them on second `API` side.

You can register middleware which gathering headers from current requests and stores them to singleton DI service (can be named like `HeadersPropagator`). When you create an `HttpClient` you can get gathered headers from `HeadersPropagator` and copy them to request to your second `API`.